# New questions show as 'new question with activity' when not sorted by activity

Tags: feature-request

When idling on the site, it's very common to see "1 new question with activity". It's a nice feature, all web 2.1ish. Awesome.

But when the questions aren't sorted by activity, it's a little misleading. It only shows up when someone posts a new question, and its text should probably be updated to reflect the actual change in the state of the system.

I'm debating whether this is considered bug or feature request. I kind of feel it's a bug, just because I'd consider it a mistake. At the same time, it's not exactly a behavioral symptom which makes me feel it's not a bug.

Example below

[image]

Comment: As far as I can tell, this feature is only available when you are in the *active questions* page. So it's not really relevant.

Comment: I am only ever on the `whatever.stackexchange.com/questions` page. Leave a beta site up overnight in a new tab on the `/questions` and you'll see it.

Comment: So this might be a bug. :)